# Flutter: Auto Complete search bar with data from 3 different Firestore collection

Tags: flutter, dart, search, google-cloud-firestore, autocomplete

I want to have an auto complete search app bar, in which data is from 3 collections which have 2 fields common in each doc of them. I want to get all docs from 3 collection and show the 2 fields as title and subtitle of the suggestion listtile. How to get suggestions data from 3, collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get data from 3 collections separately at a time, so did it another way I don't know if it's the most efficient one. Still, it might help you out.

Let you have three collections A, B, C
so what I did was I created another common collection i.e X

so when you use the fucntion addDataToA()or addDataToB() or addDataToC() , also include X in them for example:
addDataToA(
addDataToX();
)
similarly for B and C,
Now as you have done for adding data you can also do it for the update, create and delete.

For more convenience what I did was in docs of collection  A, B, C I added a field called type in which I wrote A, B, C so that while retrieving data through the collection X you can also know from which collection it came.

Hope this helps, any doubts please ask in the commenst bellow.

Answer (score 0):

If the 3 collections all have the same name, consider using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to search them.

If they have different names, or if there are many more collections of the same name that you don't want to search, you will have to query each of the 3 collections individually and merge the results in your application code.

Comment: How to query each of them and merge? And how the merged data will be transferred to search bar?

Comment: From a quick search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+two+queries, `StreamZip` looks promising.

Comment: Hey @Jagadish. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No, I couldn't make an autocomplete textfield from Firestore..could you find this anywhere? But I got data from 3 collections by adding the data which was being added to those 3 collections to one common collection.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a solution too. It might be helpful if you post a self-answer with how you merged the collections.

Comment: okk sure...I have done it please check it out